# Trying to display id of table 1 as it relates to table 3

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have three tables: exfillocation, phishkit, snapshot. We need to be able to query exfillocation.filename and print the related snapshot.id, which requires traversing the phishkit table.

exfillocation.phishkit_id is related to phishkit.id as a foreign key.

Table exfillocation schema:

```
id  exfil_location    phishkit_id
==  =========         ============
1   ['open.txt']       7442      
2   ['bot.txt']        9931
```

phishkit.snapshot_id is related to snapshot.id as a foreign key.

Phishkit schema:

```
id     snapshot_id     md5
===    ============   =====
7442      1492          f4a3954e39b90c02f4a3954e39b90c02
9931      1661          e048f240ad0845b50abe8df9124ce3fb
```

Snapshot schema:

```
id     asn           url
===    ======        =============
1661    123          badwebsite.malicious.com
1492    31           haxx0rs.hacking.com
```

I've tried reading postgresql's four different JOIN methods as well as the UNION method, but I don't seem to get the snapshot_id column returned.

I tried something awkward this this:

```
SELECT exfil_location, found_in_file, phishkit_id
    FROM public.lookup_exfillocation
    FULL OUTER JOIN public.lookup_phishkit
    ON public.lookup_exfillocation.phishkit_id = public.lookup_phishkit.id
    FULL OUTER JOIN public.lookup_snapshot
    ON public.lookup_phishkit.snapshot_id = public.lookup_snapshot.id WHERE exfil_location::text NOT LIKE ('__script.txt__') ORDER BY phishkit_id;
```

I expected to see the related lookup_snapshot.id and the related lookup_phishkit.id, which neither showed.

[image: Results not showing the related snapshot.id column]

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample, your actual result and the expected result

Comment: That query looks like it would error out since you have a where clause before your joins.

Comment: @scaisEdge completed.

Comment: @drakin8564 you're right, I copied the wrong query. I removed the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally found the solution. It came down to what columns I was SELECTing. Using a * showed all columns in the JOIN statements. Then I picked from the columns needed. The query looks like:

````
    FROM public.lookup_exfillocation
    FULL OUTER JOIN public.lookup_phishkit
    ON public.lookup_exfillocation.phishkit_id = public.lookup_phishkit.id
    FULL OUTER JOIN public.lookup_snapshot
    ON public.lookup_phishkit.snapshot_id = public.lookup_snapshot.id WHERE exfil_location::text NOT LIKE ('__script.txt__') ORDER BY phishkit_id;```
````